# How to create string when searching with get-childitem With Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to search a directory and create a batch file using a derived string, both at the same time with PowerShell (like set based processing).

For example, I'd like to do something like the following (Pseudo code):

```
Set-Content -value Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" | select "SomeString" + name
```

My first challenge is to correctly concatenate strings. I noticed if I run the following command it will return blanks for the string response.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" | select "SomeString" + name
```

Running this will return valid file names

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" | select name
```

I ultimately want to do something like the following, writing it to a file.

```
"SELECT c:\somefolder\someExecutable.exe -someParameter " + name
```

Is this possible with Powershell? If so, this could help me build a batch (.bat) file with set based processing, so it'd save me a bunch of code looping through each file I find in a folder.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want but if you are just looking to have a list of file names that are part of a bigger string that should be fairly straightforward. (You need at least PowerShell 3.0 for the `-File` switch to work.)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Output "SELECT $($_.FullName) -someparameter name"    
} | Set-Content "c:\pathtofile.txt"
```

This will take all of the files in all directories under "c:\temp". With each of those files we make a string that contains the full file path with some characters both before and after. That is then sent to file using `Set-Content`. There are other ways to concat string like in your question `"test" + "ing"` but using the subexpression `$($_.FullName)` makes it cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Man, I can't vote because I don't have enough reputation. This is spectacular. I came up with something like this, but I think I like yours a bit better:

Set-Content -Value "$envPath\env.bat" -Path $batchFileOutput

Get-ChildItem -Path $trtDir -Filter $myFilter |
ForEach-Object{
 $fileName = $_.name
 $cmd = "$envPath\valtrt.exe -l ENG DEMO $fileName "
 Add-Content -Value $cmd -Path $batchFileOutput
}

Sorry for the horrible formatting.

Comment: @BobDelamater I'm glad you found something that works for you. Does this mean you have an answer or are you looking for other pointers? If it is the former consider marking this response as the answer with the check mark under the voting toggles. Code in comments is horrible. If you need to just update your question